# Find max/min value in a Javascript set

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm developing a Javascript and d3.js application where I'd like to keep track of unique values in a an uploaded dataset. Using one of the new Javascript Set objects seems appealing, but I can't figure out a good way to extract the max and min values of the set.  My code:

```
var mySet = new Set();
mySet.add(5);
mySet.add(10);
mySet.add(20);
console.log( d3.max(mySet) );
```

This yields `undefined` rather than 20.

I've tried the `.elements()`, `.values()` and `.keys()` Set functions, which pass a SetIterator object to `d3.max()` but also return `undefined`. Using `Array.from` appears to be currently unsupported in Chrome.

Any suggestions? I realize that this may be browser-specific as Set objects get rolled out; I'm developing on Chrome v44.  I've also looked at using an object object as a dictionary, but can't figure out a concise way to get max/min to work with that structure either.

Edit: I initially asked this question using a mix of arrays and numbers as set elements. The issue still appears in Chrome when using just elements, as above

Comment: It appears that you are asking D3 to sort a Set that contains 2 elements: an array of 3 elements and a number, 21. I guess the max function is a bit lost. I would suggest adding the numbers one by one (through a loop for example) in the Set and passing an array to d3.max (check [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)).

Comment: Thanks for the catch- this issue still persists when just considering numbers as elements (edited question to reflect this).  Array.from appears to be currently unsupported in Chrome- other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`d3.max` only takes an array ([docs](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#d3_max)). Right now, you are passing in a set to `d3.max` that looks like:

```
{ [5,10,20], 21 }
```

When you should pass an array like this

```
[5,10,20,21]
```

Here's how you should do it:

```
var mySet = new Set();
mySet.add(5);
mySet.add(10);
mySet.add(20);
mySet.add(21);
myArray = []

// convert set to array
for (v of mySet) {
    myArray.push(v)
}

console.log( d3.max(myArray) );
```

Answer (score 5):

You can find Maximum and Minimum values in one line using `apply`

```
const mySet = new Set([1, 2, 9, 7, 8]);
Math.max.apply(this, [...mySet]);
Math.min.apply(this, [...mySet]);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is worth noting, as 6 years have passed since the question was posted, that as of D3 **v6** the original problem no longer persists. From that version onwards (see [changelog](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/main/CHANGES.md#d3-array)) the methods of the d3-array module accept iterables. Because a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) itself is [iterable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/@@iterator) the original code will work just fine:

```js
var mySet = new Set();
mySet.add(5);
mySet.add(10);
mySet.add(20);
console.log(d3.max(mySet));  // prints 20
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use native JavaScript destructuring operator with to find the max value in Set.

```
    const mySet = new Set([5, 10, 20]);

    const maxInSet = Math.max(...mySet);
```

Answer (score 0):

For Chrome 45+, this should be able to be done without creating a separate array by using `Set.prototype.values()` and `Array.from()` like so:

```
var mySet = new Set([1,2,3,3,2,1]);
var setMax = d3.max(Array.from(mySet.values()));
console.log(setMax);
```

Should you not want to use `d3.max()`, `Math.max()` with the spread operator will work as well:

```
var mySet = new Set([1,2,3,3,2,1]);
var setMax = Math.max(...Array.from(mySet.values()));
console.log(setMax);
```